# jake whartons viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Im having a problem here. i downloaded jake wharton. He gave an example of that which works great. But i want is from this [image]  i want to change that recent recent recent text to an activity.. so what i did is this [image], i put a class with .getname in there.. i thought it will be an activity but it convert it to text? this is the code of jake..

Test Fragment.java

```
package com.simple.viewpage;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public final class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";

    public static TestFragment newInstance(String content) {
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            builder.append(content).append(" ");
        }
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
        fragment.mContent = builder.toString();

        return fragment;
    }

    private String mContent = "???";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)) {
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.setText(mContent);
        text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(text);

        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
    }
}
```

Test FragmentAdapter.java

```
package com.simple.viewpage;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "This", "Is", "A", "Test", };

    private int mCount = CONTENT.length;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        if (count > 0 && count <= 10) {
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is his main activity:

```
package com.viewpagerindicator.sample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator;

public class SampleTabsDefault extends BaseSampleActivity {
    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Recent", "Artists", "Albums", "Songs", "Playlists", "Genres" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_tabs);

        mAdapter = new GoogleMusicAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mIndicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    }

    class GoogleMusicAdapter extends TestFragmentAdapter {
        public GoogleMusicAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return TestFragment.newInstance(SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT[position % SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT.length]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT[position % SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

I change the Content String to this:

```
private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Recent", "Artists", "Albums", "Songs", "Playlists", "Genres",ListTest.class.getName() };
```

Please help.. I want to view an activity and not convert it to text..

Comment: You don't have to tell us "help please"... we know that you need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please help.. I want to view an activity and not convert it to text..

You don't view an `Activity`, you view a `Fragment`. And you're not converting it, just retrieving its class name and using that as the label in the pager **indicator**.

> I change the Content String to this:

Those are just the labels. The contents are different. The content is retrieved in:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return TestFragment.newInstance(SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT[position % SampleTabsDefault.CONTENT.length]);
}
```

Jake put that code just an example.

It's up to you to `switch(position)` and return a new `Fragment` depending on the position you want to appear. I don't use that method (mine is slightly different), but how exactly you want to implement is up to you.

If you have other questions just ask. :-)

edited: a possible example:

```
static class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment f;
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            f= new PlaceDataFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            f= new PlaceSelectorFragment();
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not this many fragments: " + position);
        }
        //DebugUtils.debugUI("getView(): " + f.toString());
        return f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u show me how you implemented it? or can u give an example on how to do it?? pls.. thanks..

Comment: @nelzkie, done. As I said, I'm using a slightly different class that I customized. You can see that I didn't implement `getPageTitle`. In your case, I believe you just need to replicate what I did in `getItem`, except that you'll return in this `getPageTitle` (that you'll add yourself) the `CharSequence` labels instead of `Fragments`, of course.

Comment: @AlexLockwood Don't pressure me lol... and besides, I need to sleep well to catch the I/O keynote later on the web. Nexus 7/JB "ftw". :-)

Comment: @David, I only said that because I remember you mentioning how "fast" I answered that Loaders question haha :P. And yeah... I need to figure out how to watch that at work tomorrow :D. Hopefully my manager will be watching it too...

Comment: I suspected... :p I decided to venture into this knowing a kb-code ninja would jump here soon if I wasn't quick enough. I'm getting there! ;)

Comment: @David.. ^_^.. ahm about switch.. should i put the code like this? FragmentManager fm       = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment        fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_content); 
        // null, otherwise it will be.
        if (fragment == null) {
            


            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, new BasicFragment());
            ft.commit();

Comment: Please use http://pastie.org/ whenever you want to share code with us. Besides... if I can make sense of that, no... you don't handle the Fragment creation and their addition using `fm`. I'm "99% sure" (never looked at the sources) you just need to supply a `new Fragment` because the library will handle everything for you. You don't touch the manager, and that's why you just need to pass it on using the `super` call (the super class will handle it). It's probably something like this: http://pastie.org/4158318

Comment: @David.. Im sorry.. Im new to fragment and only use its basic code once in my project.. ahm your new PlaceDataFragment().. is it a class you created? if so can i have a look of it?

Comment: That class is just an example I made up, but *any* (*really*) `Fragment` will work. Even a default with its basic `onCreate` will work. If you need help creating basic Fragments to test, this is a good start: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial

Comment: @DavidCesarino hello i m trying to implement jake's directional viewpager with webviews.. is it possible.. if yes please give some hints or any coded example if it is already done.. thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand fully if you mean a Fragment with a WebView inside... the comments are very limited in space and functionality, so I suggest you opening a new question explaining your new problem in full detail about what is going wrong and what you want to achieve exactly.